# VueDraggable and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vuedraggable

I'm confused as how to correctly use vueDraggable together with Laravel.

I can drag and sort the elements in the browser but the array is not changing (when I check in the console)/ it seems to me the changes aren't reflected in the array. Shouldn't the array index numbers change after moving items?

In the overview.blade.php I have the component:

```
<qm-draggable :list="{{ $mylaravelarray }}"></qm-draggable>
```

In the qm-draggable.vue I have:

```
<template>
  <draggable group="fragenblatt" @start="drag=true" @end="endDrag" handle=".handle">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in draggablearray" :key="item.index">
        // list items here
    </li>
  </draggable>
</template>

<script>
data() {
    return {
      draggablearray:{},
    };
  },
  props: {
    list: Array,
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.draggablearray = this.list; // create a new array so I don't alter the prop directly.
  },
  [..]
  </script>
```

In the [documentation](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#props) it says, one way to pass the array is:

value

Type: Array

Required: false

Default: null

Input array to draggable component. Typically same array as referenced by inner element v-for directive.
This is the preferred way to use Vue.draggable as it is compatible with Vuex.
It should not be used directly but only though the v-model directive:

```
<draggable v-model="myArray">
```

But where do I do that? in overview.blade.php or in the component (.vue), or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `v-model` on your `draggable` as that's what will update `draggablearray`.

Also if `draggablearray` is supposed to be an array, initialise it as one, so `draggablearray:{}` should be `draggablearray:[]`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      drag: false,
      draggablearray: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "1"
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "2"
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "3"
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.7.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.16.0/vuedraggable.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="app">

    <draggable v-model="draggablearray" group="fragenblatt">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in draggablearray">
        {{item.name}}
      </li>
    </draggable>

    {{draggablearray}}

  </div>

</div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="tree-menu">

  <div class="tree-menu">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
      <div :style="indent" :class="labelClasses" @click.stop="toggleChildren">
        <i v-if="nodes" class="fa" :class="iconClasses"></i>
        <input type="checkbox" :checked="selected" @input="tickChildren" @click.stop /> {{label}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <draggable v-model="nodes" :options="{group:{ name:'g1'}}">
      <tree-menu v-if="showChildren" v-for="node in nodes" :nodes="node.nodes" :label="node.label" :depth="depth + 1" :selected="node.selected" :key="node">
      </tree-menu>
    </draggable>

  </div>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I solved it, now I get the altered array back, I achieved it with this:

1. Had to add v-model="draggablearray" in the component .vue file
2. Needed to change my 'draggablearray' in data to an Array, instead of
   object.

It looks like this now:

In the overview.blade.php I have the component:

```
<qm-draggable :list="{{ $mylaravelarray }}"></qm-draggable>
```

In the qm-draggable.vue I have:

```
<template>
  <draggable v-model="draggablearray" group="fragenblatt" @start="drag=true" @end="endDrag" handle=".handle">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in draggablearray" :key="item.index">
        // list items here
    </li>
  </draggable>
</template>

<script>
data() {
    return {
      draggablearray:[], //has to be an Array, was '{}' before
    };
  },
  props: {
    list: Array,
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.draggablearray = this.list; // create a new array so I don't alter the prop directly.
  },
  [..]
  </script>
```